# Where to put pre- state setting mutations in Flux Design Pattern

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, flux

I'm working on an application in Vue with Vuex using the Flux design pattern.

I'm running into what I feel to be bad methodology by having to do small duplications in the code. I'm hoping I'm just seeing something wrong, and that it's just not a shortcoming of this design pattern. (I am new to Flux design pattern)

Here is the situation:
I'm reading out to a data source, and getting a list of Users. The Users are set onto their own state object once returned from the API.

> Actions -> API -> Mutation -> State

However, there are some time-of-pull computations that need to happen to each user in the list. For example, we have the Date of Birth of each user, but I need to know how old they are. Since mutation methods cannot call other mutation methods, I can not have the `setUsers` mutation call another mutation to get the age before assigning the list to the state.

If I return the state pre-calculations, then for everywhere I need make the call to `setUsers`, I'd have to loop over the Users, and call individual mutations for each User to set the age instead of something like this within the mutation:

```js
setUsers(state,users) {
  state.users = setAgeData(users);
},
setAgeData(users) {
  users.forEach(user => {
    user.age = getAge(user.dob);
  });
  return users;
},
getAge(dateString) {
  var today = new Date();
  var birthDate = new Date(dateString);
  var age = today.getFullYear() - birthDate.getFullYear();
  var m = today.getMonth() - birthDate.getMonth();
  if (m < 0 || (m === 0 && today.getDate() < birthDate.getDate())) {
    age--;
  }
  return age;
},
```

Is there any better way to do the on the fly computations before coming back with the state?

Comment: @tony19 Where would you place the functions? Im rather new to Vue, so maybe this is a dumb question, but i dont believe i could use a mixin, would you just add them to the end of the mutations export?

Comment: Right, you wouldn't use a *Vue mixin* because it wouldn't apply here, but you could technically use a regular mixin, or a local function, or an imported function. I'll provide an example in an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`setAgeData()` and `getAge()` are not actually mutations (they don't match the signature of a mutation). They should just be utility functions (moved outside the store) that `setUsers()` calls, and I don't see any problem with that.

For example, you could move `setAgeData()` and `getAge()` into a local function:

```js
// store/index.js
function setAgeData() {/*...*/}
function getAge() {/*...*/}

export default new Vuex.Store({
  mutations: {
    setUsers(state, users) {
      state.users = setAgeData(users)
    }
  }
})
```

Or you could move them into a separate file to be imported:

```js
// store/user-utils.js
export function setAgeData() {/*...*/}
export function getAge() {/*...*/}

// store/index.js
import { setAgeData } from './user-utils'

export default new Vuex.Store({
  mutations: {
    setUsers(state, users) {
      state.users = setAgeData(users)
    }
  }
})
```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/organizing-vuex-mutations-so6d2?file=/src/store/index.js:0-267)